# AMD Catalyst keeps crashing

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2012, amd-catalyst

[image]

I have Windows Server 2012 running with 3 screens and a Radeon HD 5xxx series video card. I've installed all the versions of the Catalyst software including the betas. Every now and again randomly, the screen will drop from 1920x2560 to 800x600, and upon restarting, I receive this error message.

Any idea on how to fix this? Everything is updated.

Comment: run the CCC in Win7 compatibility mode. Does this work?

Comment: [http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) does not seem to have a driver for server 2012. Are you trying to use the windows 8 drivers on 2012 ?